# Azure Web Job App.Config Transformation not working in TFS Release pipeline

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-webjobs

I have an azure web job that I am deploying onto a test environment using TFS Release pipeline. Most of my configuration settings are in the Config settings of App Service Web app except the WCF end point section which is in the app.config.

Here are the settings I have on both the solution as well as build/release pipelines -

- Kept the config files (app.config, app.release.config, app..config) of "Content" build action.
- Removed the <DependentUpon>.
- Verified the config transform files are in the drop file in the same
  directory
  ".....\Local\Package\PackageTmp\app_data\jobs\continuous\JobName"
- On the build pipeline I have disabled the config transformation using
  /p:TransformWebConfigEnabled=false
- On the release pipeline I am using "Azure App Service deploy" version
  4.* with XML Transformation enabled.

But somehow, the deployed JobName.exe.config doesn't get transformed with neither app.release.config nor app.environment.config.

Could someone help me on what I am missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But somehow, the deployed JobName.exe.config doesn't get transformed
> with neither app.release.config nor app.environment.config.

Please check [Configuration transform file naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#configuration-transform-file-naming-conventions)：

XML transformation will be run on the *.config file for transformation configuration files named *.Release.config or *..config and will be executed in the following order:

- `*.Release.config (for example, fabrikam.Release.config)`
- `*.<stage>.config (for example, fabrikam.Production.config)`
  For example, if your package contains the following files:

  Web.config,
  Web.Debug.config,
  Web.Release.config,
  Web.Production.config

and your stage name is `Production`, the transformation is applied for `Web.config` with `Web.Release.config` followed by `Web.Production.config`.

**To sum up:**

It's expected behavior that your `JobName.exe.config` doesn't get transformed. Cause the `XML Transformation` options is used to transform your `app.config` file with `app.release.config`. (You can check content of your app.config file, it should be changed.)

To get a more powerful transform task, consider using [File Transform task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61092493/10910450).

Comment: Hi Lance, Thanks for your response. You are correct, I just noticed the app.config is transformed. I will try the File Transform Task. But my worry is, the webjob artifact is in a zip folder in the drop, do I need to unzip it first, apply File Transform, then again zip it back and then pass it to the App Service Deploy Task?

Comment: @Rony No, File Transform task can directly transform the files within a zip file. You don't need to unzip it manually, good news? If my answer helps, please consider [accepting it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442)~

Comment: Wow.. that's great. Thank you very much.